# How to display results of my if statement

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm working on a mini flutter project that's supposed to give you a grade based on the score you enter.

I've put an if statement in my onPressed (`flat button`) saying that if the number entered is greater than or equal to a parameter (eg 70) then it should return the statement “Congrats you have an A. I want to do this for all the other grades."

*THE PROBLEM*
In the code when I tap on my submit button I get the error

> *"the method >= was called on null." *

Ps:

- I'm a beginner and this is the section of the code involving the problem. The `textfield` area which has the onChanged method and my variable called input. Input receives whatever is put into the `textfield`.
- the next part is the `Flatbutton` which is supposed to carry out the function when pressed
- Lastly, there is the text widget which displays the content of my second variable called output. it shows a different statement whenever there is a different grade.

```
               TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                        ),
                      focusedBorder:OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                      ) ,
                      hintText: "Submit your grade",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 16,),
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
                        ),
                        onChanged: ( score){
                          input = score as int;
                        },
                      ),
               FlatButton(
                        onPressed: (){
                          if (input >= 70 ){
                            setState(() {
                              output="Congrats! You have an A";
                            });
                            if (input<=69) {
                              setState(() {
                                output="Well done you have an B! Keep Working Hard";
                              });
                              if(input<=50){
                                setState(() {
                                  output="Sorry you have failed.";
                                });
                              }else{
                                setState(() {
                                  output="Invalid value.Please try again";

                                });
                              }
                            }}
                          },
                        child: Container(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.amber,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)
                          ),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 100),
                          child: Center(child: Text("Submit",style: 
                            TextStyle(fontSize: 16,),)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 80,),
                      Text(output,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),)
```

*Error Message*

> ════════ Exception caught by gesture
> ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
> The method '>=' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: >=(70)
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
> #1      _homeState.build.
> (package:flutter_app1/screens/home.dart:151:37)
> #2      _InkResponseState._handleTap
> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:779:19)
> #3      _InkResponseState.build.
> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:862:36)
> #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback
> (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
> *...*
> Handler: "onTap"
> Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#99edd
> debugOwner: GestureDetector
> state: ready
> won arena
> finalPosition: Offset(168.9, 353.1)
> finalLocalPosition: Offset(168.9, 44.1)
> button: 1
> sent tap down

Lastly, what will change if I use a `container` and `gesture detector` instead of a submit button ? I know that I will use onTap instead of onPressed but is there anything else ?

Comment: "score as int" is not a cast, it's basically a type relabel, and does not change the underlying data.  To get from a String to an int, use int.parse(theString).

Comment: Thanks so much. It works perfectly for the first if function but the remaining ones aren’t working. If I put in a number less than 70 it doesn’t show the corresponding output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I hope you declare `int input = 0`. If not, declare it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "as int", you should use int.parse like this:

```
input  = int.parse(score);
```